# Can we extend the scope of our site by including support for Ukrainian refugees abroad?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

This is essentially what is proposed [here](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6873) (and [here](https://dou.ua/forums/topic/19652/#2365512), and [here](https://dou.ua/forums/topic/16114/#2365514)).

My personal feeling about this proposal is between neutral and positive. Despite this is absolutely not the thing I wanted this site to be dedicated for (I wanted it to be purely linguistic), but sometimes the times require us to do more than we want.

Pros: it might really help the people. Cons: we (moderators and active users) may lack knowledge/competence to adequately maintain the new topic.

Secondary question is: Would the Stack Exchange organization itself (Stack Exchange administration) allow us to suddenly extend the list of allowed topics? But I think this question is secondary, we should first decide it for ourselves (and then we can try convincing higher-level Stack Exchange administration if required).

Third-degree question is related to the language. The proposal author ([Tatiana](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/u/4511)) expressed the proposal in Russian (and, of course, in wrong place). Maybe they assume that, if the topic itself would be allowed, Russian language is allowed as well. But, again, I think this question is third-order-priority: even if we allow the new topic only in Ukrainian and English, it might be great help for refugees as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, we can not and we should not. As well as [Expatriates.StackExchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) should not allow questions on Zanzibarian language's adjective conjugation on the premise that you are an expat living in Zanzibar who's having a hard time learning a deeper aspect of Zanzibarian language.

You are an expat or a displaced person — you need a site where **other expats or people familiar with expats' problems** can read your question and answer it.

- You want to help — make your own site. Advertise it here.
- Your expats only speak Ukrainian and cannot ask in English — take their requests, translate it and ask at Expats.SE.
- Ask at [Expats.Meta.SE](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/) if they would temporarily accept questions in Ukrainian. It is your responsibility to prove there will be sufficient number of those who can answer such questions and/or volunteers to make their posts bilingual UA+EN.
- And God forbid you from promoting the muscovian language
  which is well-deservedly *delenda est*. Let us keep at least this place clean of that cancer.

Comment: On the one hand, that topic would be formally offtopic; and I respect your position on that. On the other hand, that's maybe not the best time for stubbornly keeping the formalities; all world is now going giant steps to help us; it would be simply weird if we refuse to do a small one in order to help our own refugees.

Comment: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ is not a bad idea. But it's about all expatriates, not specifically about refugees and not specifically about Ukrainian refugees of this war. It may happen that our site would be "closer" (and untuitively more obvious) for Ukrainian refugees than https://expatriates.stackexchange.com. Still — would you mind asking on expatriates' if they could (at least temporarily) allow Ukrainian language?

Comment: As for allowing Russian language, let's put it in the following way: let's assume that allowed languages will remain only Ukrainian and English and focus on discussing only the (possibly temporary) scope extension.

Comment: Re: *stubbornly keeping the formalities* — it's a change. One should not explain why to leave things the way they are. The proponent of the change should convince the others. You have not convinced me, but let's see if you have convinced someone else. Re: *t may happen that our site would be "closer" for Ukrainian refugees* — that's a big sign that we/they have chosen a wrong platform at all. SE, as a platform, is **very** slow against rapidly changing events.

Comment: Re: *would you mind asking on expatriates* — sorry, no. Such actions require powerful support of other UASE users. I stepped down from the moderator's position here specifically because you can not do things like that alone. I begged for UASE community help for years when I tried to convince the Westerners about our war and fought against muscovian trolls (empowered by some heavily biased diamond Moderators) at Politics.SE and Travel.SE. And again, I left alone. Sorry, but I have other things to do. At places where I am not alone.

Comment: As for now, I was able to convince 2 old participants (and was unable to convince you). However, the main factor for me is the further activity of Tatiana — if Tatiana disappears (and for now there were no new messages from Tatiana on any of the platforms she expressed her proposal), then nothing is going to happen anyway (I don't have a feeling that the old community will be able to do the new work without active support of new members).